# Bluemix Mongodb : Failed to authenticate

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud

I am using bluemix mongodb experimental service but I cannot connect from my terminal to create new collections. 
i tried to ping the host which is specified in environment variables but it is timed out. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can only use the MongoDB experimental service from inside your Bluemix application. It does not allow you to connect to the database from your desktop.

If you need full MongoDB capabilities you can try to use the MongoDB by Compose [1] service also available in Bluemix.

[1] https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/mongodb-by-compose/