# Docker app Node.js connection with Bluemix experimental mongodb service

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ibm-cloud

I have a basic Node.js application running perfectly on Cloud Foundry using Bluemix experimental mongoDB service and a node runtime.

I am willing to dockerized the application. Working fine locally on my computer (one container for the app and one container for Mongo using the official mongo image).But I have issues to get it running on Bluemix cloud.

I have created a cloud foundry bridge application with the mongoDB experimental service binded and from the command line

> > cf ic run --name mytodolist -e CCS_BIND_APP=bridgeapp000 IMAGE_NAME

Container is successfully created and I can access the application but the application cannot connect to the database. Here the application logs I get:

```html
Using the experimental service and uri is mongodb://70b7204a-3607-474d-ac81-34fdb638d714:ac44ef2d-87ee-48aa-bbee-3d08a18459c4@23.246.199.107:10137/db
dbURI is: mongodb://70b7204a-3607-474d-ac81-34fdb638d714:ac44ef2d-87ee-48aa-bbee-3d08a18459c4@23.246.199.107:10137/db
connecting
App listening on port 8080
mongodb://70b7204a-3607-474d-ac81-34fdb638d714:ac44ef2d-87ee-48aa-bbee-3d08a18459c4@23.246.199.107:10137/db
disconnected
dbURI is: mongodb://70b7204a-3607-474d-ac81-34fdb638d714:ac44ef2d-87ee-48aa-bbee-3d08a18459c4@23.246.199.107:10137/db
connecting
Error in MongoDb connection: Error: failed to connect to [23.246.199.107:10137]
disconnected
dbURI is: mongodb://70b7204a-3607-474d-ac81-34fdb638d714:ac44ef2d-87ee-48aa-bbee-3d08a18459c4@23.246.199.107:10137/db
connecting
Error in MongoDb connection: [object Object]
```

Note that in my Dockerfile, I have added a sleep function before to start the node server.

> > CMD sleep 60 && node server.js

Any idea of where the problem could come from? Could it be that the experimental service is not accessible from the Docker containers on Bluemix?

For information, here the code I use to retrieve the database URI:

```js
// MongoDB - connection URI
if(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES){
 var services = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
 if(services['mongolab']) {
  var uri = services['mongolab'][0].credentials.uri;
 } 
 if(services['mongodb-2.4']){
  var uri = services['mongodb-2.4'][0].credentials.url;
  console.log("Using the experimental service and uri is "+uri);
 }
} else {
 if (process.env.DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR){
  uri = "mongodb://" + process.env.DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR + ":" + process.env.DB_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT +"/docker";
 } else{
  uri = ""
 }
}

module.exports = {
 url: uri
};
```

and the code to establish the connection with the database:

```js
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('connecting', function() {
    console.log('connecting');
});

db.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error('Error in MongoDb connection: ' + error);
    mongoose.disconnect();
});

db.on('connected', function() {
    console.log('connected!');
});

db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('connection open');
});

db.on('reconnected', function () {
    console.log('reconnected');
});

db.on('disconnected', function() {
    console.log('disconnected');
    console.log('dbURI is: '+database.url);
    mongoose.connect(database.url, {server:{auto_reconnect:true, socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 }}, replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS : 30000 } }});
  });
console.log('dbURI is: '+ database.url);
mongoose.connect(database.url, {server:{auto_reconnect:true}});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluemix Mongodb : Failed to authenticate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797707/bluemix-mongodb-failed-to-authenticate)

Comment: You can only connect to MongoDB experimental from Bluemix applications. It does not work from IBM containers. This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797707/bluemix-mongodb-failed-to-authenticate/34798023